# why is my custom UIButton subclass not triggering touch up IBAction?

Tags: swift

this probably has something to do with the fact that I am overriding touchesBegan in my custom subclass:

```swift
class myCustomButton: UIButton {

override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("TOUCHES BEGAN OVERRIDE CALLED")
        originalColor = self.backgroundColor ?? .red
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.animateScale()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
//...
}
```

touchesEnded is similarly overridden, and both of these functions are called and print debug statements to console on button press. however, the code in the button pressed IBAction from my view controller is never run

```swift
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {  
    print("this is never executed")
    //...
}
```

I have double checked that the IBOutlet is not broken and changed the (_ sender: Any) to (_ sender: AnyObject) both to no avail. any insights would be appreciated

Comment: also, touches, the first argument of touchesBegan, is empty when I debug. maybe that's another clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah ok, figured it out. in my custom button initializer I added a subview which, by default, had userInteractionEnabled set to true. setting `userInteractionEnabled = true` on my custom button object and `userInteractionEnabled = false` on my view before adding it as a subview allows my custom button to capture the touch and handle it properly rather than the view capturing the touch

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding touchesBegan, try overriding the sendAction function of your UIButton:

```
override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
    super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    //Insert your code here
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried that and it seems like my overridden sendAction() is never called. why use sendAction instead of touchesBegan?

Comment: sendAction() directly deals with the action that is performed after a UIButton receives a touch event. Maybe check to make sure that you initialized your UIButton as a myCustomButton?